# Importing offline conversion in to GA in batches - what data set to use?

Tags: google-analytics

What type of data set should I be using to upload conversion data in to Google Analytics? We are limited to receiving the conversion data in monthly batches, so we can't set up something to use the measurement protocol directly.

I want to upload a csv that contains the user IDs that converted in the past month, and have that show up as a conversion(i.e. goal) in GA. I'm reading the documentation but I don't see anything specifically for just uploading conversion data, they are describing adding extra dimensions, but I just want a simple conversion counter (goal) incremented (i.e. create a goal in GA, and then upload the user IDs so the goal gets incremented for these users) .

How do I do this? It seems like it should be easy, but like I said I can't seem to find a specific example of doing this

Answer (score 2):

A goal conversion in Google Analytics is either a url destionantion, an event or one of page depth or session duration. So to create goal conversions via data upload you'd need to be able to upload pageviews or events and that's not possible.

Also you cannot "upload a user id" - the user id must be present in Analytics to join the incoming data to the data in analytics (you know that, others who read this answer might not, so I spell it out).

You could upload a file that contains user ids for converted users and a custom dimension with the value "converted" so that at least you can segment them out via the segmentation tool. At that point you will hit a snag that is somewhat [hidden in the documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/4524584?ref_topic=6015090):

> Uploaded data needs to be processed before it can show up in reports.
>   Once processing is complete, it may take up to 24 hours before the
>   imported data will begin to be applied to incoming hit data.

"Applied to incoming data". So the plan to join the uploaded data with existing user ids won't work, either.

As far as I read the documentation the only data point that can be overwritten are campaign information (not on a per-user basis) and refund data. So unless you want to give all converted users a 1 Cent refund to be able to segment them out I don't really see how data uploads are going to help you.

If you need to join analytics data with user data from you backend I suggest to pull the data from Analytics via the API and create the report outside of Google Analytics.

Comment: So just so I'm clear - there isn't a way to import conversions (that happened in the past) and tie them back to a Google user ID? With regards to uploading the user ID, what I meant is the user ID is passed along to the CRM, so at the end of the month we can get a list of user IDs together with the conversions. This would then be uploaded in to GA, and connected using the ID present in GA and the conversion report. But this is not possible? This the basic approach we use in SiteCatalyst, but there is no equivalent in GA?

Comment: I'm usually careful with absolutes, but the documentation says no and when I tried anyway it didn't work.  This might be because Google does not store all the raw data, (so things might be different with the premium version) but unless someone much more knowledgable with GA than me steps in I'd say this does not work. I think it's one of the major advantages/selling points of Adobe Analytics that it offers much more in terms of working with historical data.

Comment: Dang. What about sending this data via the measurement protocol? That is, send pageviews via MP to a url defined as a conversion (along with captured GA ID). Is the MP in real time, meaning if I send all the pageview data at the end of the month it will look like all conversions happened on that day?

Comment: I'm afraid so. You cannot send timestamps with your data. Maybe you could really try to record a bogus transaction for every user as a goal and then refund all non-converters to see if leaves you with the proper conversions, but I haven't tried this and it sounds like a really horrible workaround.

Comment: One more thing:
 

"Imported data will begin to be applied to incoming hit data."


Does this mean uploaded data can only be applied to hit data coming in after it's been uploaded? How does that even work? In the example in the documentation (where they upload user IDs together with food category), does this mean future visits from the existing user IDs will have the added dimension, but not new vistis? Seems an awkward limitation to have it only apply to returning visits...or am I misunderstanding what you're saying?

Comment: OK got it re: measurement protocol. At least we'd have the sum total conversions and the users they belong to, we'd just be limited to looking at it over the time period the conversion reports we receive cover. Thanks for all the answers btw, I don't often get to discuss with other people in analytics so forgive me for the grilling :)

Comment: I would recommend you go shopping for second opinions - I'm really very knowlegdable with  Google Analytics but that doesn't mean I know everything (especially with more recently added features).